# PHP Combine 2 form variables into one

Tags: php

I have two variables I need to combine into a single variable.  Each variable has two sets of conditions.  I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  I'm trying to use || as OR but am getting a syntax error.

```
$JobType = ($RepairType==17) && isset($_POST['Tankless']) && ($_POST['Tankless'] !=1 ) ? 63 : $RepairType;
$JobType = ($RepairType==17) && isset($_POST['GasWaterHeater']) && ($_POST['GasWaterHeater'] !=1 ) ? 60 : $RepairType;
```

I've tried:

```
$JobType = ($RepairType==17) && isset($_POST['Tankless']) && ($_POST['Tankless'] !=1 ) ? 63 || ($RepairType==17) && isset($_POST['GasWaterHeater']) && ($_POST['GasWaterHeater'] !=1 ) ? 60 : $RepairType;
```

And also this to "wrap" the conditions together between the || with no luck either:

```
$JobType = (($RepairType==17) && isset($_POST['Tankless']) && ($_POST['Tankless'] !=1 ) ? 63) || (($RepairType==17) && isset($_POST['GasWaterHeater']) && ($_POST['GasWaterHeater'] !=1 ) ? 60) : $RepairType;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try with classic if and see what you get...

Comment: Yup, stop using ternary expressions for such complicated conditions.

Comment: The limit of ternary operators should be "cond ? true_value : false_value". Anything outside of that and the code just makes your eyes hurt.

Comment: Computers don't have eyes and this is hardly a complicated condition.

Comment: Bad bad bad :-(

Comment: Real world. Real world. Real world.  Works Perfectly. Works Perfectly. Works Perfectly.  LOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you're looking for:

```
$JobType = ($RepairType==17) ? (
    (isset($_POST['Tankless']) && ($_POST['Tankless'] !=1)) ? 63 : (
        (isset($_POST['GasWaterHeater']) && ($_POST['GasWaterHeater'] !=1)) ? 60 : $RepairType
    )
) : $RepairType;
```

to simplify reading, you could write it like that:

```
$tankless = isset($_POST['Tankless']) && ($_POST['Tankless'] !=1 );
$gasheater = isset($_POST['GasWaterHeater']) && ($_POST['GasWaterHeater'] !=1 );

$JobType = ($RepairType==17) ? ($tankless ? 63 : ($gasheater ? 60 : $RepairType)) : $RepairType;
```

Comment: "It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious" http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: @miken32 Well, not when using parentheses at the right places. Unrelated, but some of the parentheses serve no purpose here (around `$_POST['Tankless'] != 1` or `$RepairType == 17` for instance).